# clientHeight returns zero

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating the DOM elements dynamically using JavaScript. I need to get height of one div to do the slide down animation. But when i use clientHeight its always returning a 0. offsetHeight also do the same. I'm getting the div when i tried console.log(). So its not because the element is not loaded in DOM. Initially i set style display:none for the div to hide it. Is this the reason for the problem? Please someone help me.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0].parentNode.children[1].clientHeight;
```

I tried the below code to avoid the problem of display:none. Still clientHeight returns 0.

```
if(obj.style.display == "none"){ // if it's allready hidden we slide it down
   obj.style.visibility = "hidden";
   obj.style.display = "block";
   height = obj.offsetHeight;
   obj.style.visibility = "visible";
   slideDown(obj,0,height,Math.ceil(height/timeToSlide));
}
```

Comment: Save the element height in a var before hiding it, and if your element have a CSS relative height (ex. `height: 100%`), make sure all his parents also have a height value, including the html element.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I'm creating a toggle description div which is initially not visible. Also i don't know the exact height of the div. It varies as the content of the description. So i'm giving the height as auto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elements styled with `display:none` will register 0 for its dimensions. Try applying this instead:

```
div.myClass { position:absolute; left:-999em; }
```

Same effect, but your `div` will still have its dimensions.

Comment: I tried making visibility:hidden, display:block and then clientHeight. Still it returns zero.

Comment: Why are you setting `visibility` to `hidden`? These styles I mention in my answer move the `div` offscreen, in effect hiding it.

Comment: This worked but the problem is i'm getting height of the element as 20 even though it have 60px. When i give left:-999em  height is getting reduced to 20px. Any solution to this?

Comment: Thanks guys got the problem. I didn't specified width so when I move the element left its width increases and hence the height decreasing along with it. Thanks for the support :)

Comment: position:absolute did the work in my case

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery you can get the height like this.

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0].parentNode.children[1]).height()
```

Comment: I want this without any library.